# FFmpeg: Changing from "amerge" to "amix" enables playback of video on safari browser but why its not playing with amerge?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am using amerge two add two audios. The video plays fine on chrome but its not getting played on safari. But when i change from "**amerge**" to "**amix**", then it works on both but slowing down the composition time. Please suggest what's wrong with it.

Comment: amix consolidates channels - 2ch + 2ch = 2ch whereas amerge adds them - 2ch + 2ch = 4ch. Browsers may not support more than 2 channels.

Comment: @Gyan is there a way to restrict channel to 2 while using **amerge** ?. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Add a  `pan=stereo` filter afterwards. Or -ac 2 as an output option

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Gyan